# Another place that project tool configuration files can be placed other than root?

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, guard

When using multiple tools like Guard, Rake, and Bundler which store their configuration files in the projects root, the root folder starts to become cluttered with development debris like:

- Guardfile
- Rakefile
- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock

And who knows what else if other tools are used...

Is there some where else that the configuration files for these tools can be stored that would still allow them to be invoked in the same manner?

Answer (score 1):

Rake accepts --rakefile or -f [filename]
Bundler accepts --gemfile [filename]

You could therefore create a directory, e.g. 'toolfiles' and put Rakefile and Gemfile in there. You would be stuck, of course, with including the filename each time you used the tool.

I have no idea about Guardfile.